# React cannot set div to take 100% of screen height

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to make the first div in my App.js take 100% height:

App.css:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
  return <div style={{ height: "100%", backgroundColor: "red" }}></div>;
}
```

The App component is rendered as default by index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The result is a blank white screen, not red. Why doesn't the div rely on the parent (body) and then takes 100% of the height?

EDIT: I cannot use the 100vh trick, I would be happy to know what's the reason for the direct children of the body that cannot inherit the body's properties, specifically in React of course

Comment: How is your `App` component rendered? Normally you would attach it to an existing element on the page, which would probably cause this problem if it isn't also styled to 100% height.

Comment: I edited my question to show how App is rendered, it's rendered as default, can the way it's rendered cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `100vh` (`1vh` is relative to 1% of the height of the viewport):

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ minHeight: "100vh", background: "red" }}></div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Or you have to traverse the DOM tree and make sure all parent elements are `100%` height:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100%", background: "red" }}></div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
html, body, #root {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I should have mentioned in my post that I can't use this trick because I already have a header above, so using it will make the page higher than 100%. Does it mean that in React you cannot use 100% height because something interrupts the direct relationship between the body element and its direct children?

Comment: This isn't a React issue, but an *issue* with calculating HTML element heights. Each HTML element is essentially 0 by 0 pixels, so if you don't specify a parent height, then each parent element is only as tall as its children elements.

Comment: But I did specify the parents (body/html) to be 100% height, is that what you mean? I'm sorry if I still don't get it

Comment: All **PARENT** elements need to have a height; otherwise, the parent is only as tall as its children (if it's children are 0px tall, then it is 0px tall). This means all parent elements from `html` -> `body` -> `div.root` -> ...etc allllllllllllllllll the way down the DOM tree need to have height.

Comment: Yes I understand, but if the body element has a height, and then the first div in App component has a height as well, which parent doesn't have a height and thus preventing the background color from appearing? Isn't it just two elements we're talking about here?

Comment: The first div in a React app is not going to be the one written within the `App` component. The first div element is the one assigned to `React.render` (which is usually div.root). See the 2nd example above for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
height:'100vh'
```

it works for me.
vh = view height, React seems to respond better to this unit than percent sometimes.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot use this in my app. I have a header above that div